# $firebaseArray $indexFor() not finding key when given value

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have this firebase:

```
users: {
   userId: {
      notifications: {
         notificationId: "Notification"
      }
   }
}
```

When given "Notification", I'm trying to find its notificationId (which is generated from the push() method) so I can eventually delete it. According to the docs, the $indexFor() method should do this for me. Here's my code:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://url.firebaseio.com/');

$scope.dismissNotification = function(notification) {
   var notificationRef = ref.child('users/' + $scope.currentUser.id + '/notifications');
   var notifications = $firebaseArray(notificationRef);
   notifications.$loaded().then(function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     console.log(data.$indexFor(notification));
   }).catch(function(error) {
     console.log('Error: ' + error);
   });
};
```

The first log is the correct object with the notification string inside that I'm looking for, but the second log returns -1, when I want it to return the notificationId associated with it.

Comment: What is `notification` in this example? Is it an element that exists inside `notifications`? If so, how did you verify this? If not, what is it? Why is $firebaseArray() defined inside of dismissNotification()? This doesn't make a lot of sense. (We're downloading all data in a path to find one element in that path instead of looking up that item directly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but this is the simplest way to find the key for a given value:

```
var notificationRef = ref.child('users/' + $scope.currentUser.id + '/notifications');

var query = notificationRef.orderByValue().equalTo(notification);

query.once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key());
});
```

Comment: That worked for me, thanks. Do you have any idea why the [$indexFor() function](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-indexforkey) doesn't work?

Comment: Most likely, `notification` is not an element that exists in the array (since it was passed into the method before the array was created) and therefore can't be found in it.